# Upgrade Mockito illegal reflective access operation

Tags: java, mockito

I am upgrading a library to Java 11 from Java 8. I'm using Maven 3.8.x, Spring boot 2, Mockito-core 4.2.0. I am receiving the following warning message:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.RefelectionMemberAccessor
```

In doing some research I found some possible solutions, but none have seemed to work. I've tried using `--add-opens` in arg line, upgraded Mockito from 3.8.0 to 4.2.0, upgraded Byte Buddy.

Note: I'm not sure if I used the `--add-opens` arg correctly. I'm a bit confused as to what the `<module>/<package>=VALUE` needs to be in my case. I thought I had it correct, but it didn't help.

I have other micro-services that inherit this library and use Mockito in tests as well that are working fine. In those micro-services, we overrode the java version and updated the necessary dependencies in the pom of those projects.

*** this is giving me a null pointer, but not sure why. I wasn't getting a null pointer on these tests when running on java 8 ***
Example of class test failing:

```
@RunWith(MocktioJunitRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

@Mock
private Authentication authentication;

  @Before
  public void init() {
  Mockito.when(authentication.getDetails()).thenReturn(someReturn);
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:311)
at org.springframework.security.core.Authentication$MockitoMock$1943314113.getDetails(UnknownSource)
```

Comment: It's a warning not an error (it will only be an error starting from Java 16).

Comment: It is crash running the test

Comment: If there is a crash running a test, then you're probably focusing on the wrong issue, because the illegal reflective access warning doesn't cause that (it's just a warning that something is done that will be disallowed in the future). Posting a [mre] would help.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, I belive you are correct on further inspection I ma getting a null pointer exception on each test. It stems from the init method I have. When trying to mock a method from the Authentication class as shown in my edit above. When running on java 8 I don't get this exception.

Comment: Without a [mre] that is impossible to answer.

Comment: My tests are failing before a test is even ran. It's running the init method we have coded to run before each test at the same line giving the same null pointer exception. When running the any tests in debug I can see that the Mock initializes, but still gets null pointer on mocked method call in init method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, your test class has some mistakes, you didn't initialize mocks, change it:

```
public class SomeClassTest {

@Mock
private Authentication authentication;

@InjectMocks
private YourTestService yourTestService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp(){
  initMocks(this);
}

  @Test
  public void init() {

  //put test code
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a small comment to explain why this dependency is needed.

Comment: I can but I'd like to get feedback from the author

Comment: Hi @DmitriiBykov, Adding this dependency caused the warning to no longer show up, but I think my real issue is that I am getting null pointer exceptions. I am not sure why as these tests ran on java 8 with no issues. I have edited my post to show an example of my issue.

Comment: I tried adding initMocks and the openMocks since initMocks is deprecated. Did not work. I thought when you use @RunWith(MocktioJunitRunner.class) it already takes care of all that. In debug I can see that my mocks are being initialized, but The one I referenced above is failing for some reason on mocked method call in my setUp method.

Comment: @DmitriiB Adding the dependency does resolve the warning message. But do you want to explain why it is needed? and any side effects that should I be aware of after adding this?